# Redirect user when the db is empty

Tags: laravel, redirect

I have a one to many relationship between user and team.

If a user registers, he will be forwarded to "/welcome" on the first login and must select a team, the team_id is stored in the user table.

The problem is that the user can bypass this process by entering another url from the side. How can I redirect the user from all pages to /welcome if he has not yet selected a team and how can I lock the page for the user if he has selected a team?

I've already looked at the middleware of laravel but do not understand how I can realize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you said you should use middleware .... basically you create a middleware lets call it `TeamMiddleware`

in that you check if user hasn't select his team  and if so you redirect him back to select team link

```
if(is_null(Auth::user()->team_id))
return redirect(route('team_select'));
```

and then you wrap you links in the TeamMiddleware

```
    Route::group([ 'middleware' => 'TeamMiddleware' ], function () {

        Route::post('/link1' ,  'LinkController@func1);
        Route::post('/link2' ,  'LinkController@func1);
        Route::post('/link3' ,  'LinkController@func1);
        Route::post('/link4' ,  'LinkController@func1);

    });

    Route::post('/team/select' ,  'LinkController@select_team)->name('team_select');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works. Is there a possibility to lock the /welcome page if the user has chosen a team?

Comment: or do I need a new middleware for that?

Comment: if you want to check a condition on multiple link and/or execute an action before they run ... yes you need to use a middleware